# CSS3 media queries triggering late

Tags: drupal, responsive-design

I have a simple set of media queries in a Drupal site I am working on. The media queries are triggering, however, each is triggering pixels late ("max-width: 1075px" is applying at 977px and "max-width: 797px" is applying at 724px which amounts to about 90.8% in both examples).

Note: the following code sample is written in SASS.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1075px)
@media screen and (max-width: 797px)
```

It is occurring across Chrome 21.0.x, Firefox 14.0.1 and Safari 6.0 running on OS X 10.7.4 (Lion). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1075px)
{
}
```

and make sure you have a proper meta tag setup:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Internet Explorer 11 and lower. I know that wasn't one of the affected browsers in the initial post, but this seems to be the only question about this issue of "media queries triggering late". I wanted to share my solution for anyone else having the same problem.

It seems that you need to normalize the viewport, within your css, using this line:

```
@-ms-viewport { width: device-width; }
```

I was able to find the solution here:

http://blog.adrianroselli.com/2013/05/ie10-metro-and-media-queries.html